# Drop in right div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the HTML5 Drag and drop tutorial from w3 school.

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

The place I drop things are here:

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

This is the example from w3schools. I have expended the drop part a little bit, having:

```
<div id="columna" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <div id="elementa">AAAA</div>
  <div id="elementb">BBBB</div>
</div>
```

Then comes the problem. When I drag an element into "columna" I want to append it to the list of elements. But. The code will pick up "elementa" as the id of where I drop it if I drop over the A's etc. Is there some way of always getting the parent where the ondrop-action is defined?

As a workaround I've created function to check if the id I pick up contains the string "column" and if not looking in the parent object all the way until I find a "column". (The example above is a little simplified, there might potentially be more levels of div's. And some of these divs wouldn't normally need an ID at all.)

So. Is it possible to find the ID of the div with the ondrop action?

I tried this in the Tryid Editor from W3 school as suggested below. My problem is that the image will append to the blue or red div, even if it's the yellow one having ondrop action.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
   #div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
   </style>
   <script>
   function allowDrop(ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
   }

   function drag(ev) {
     ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
   }

   function drop(ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
     var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
     ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>

   <p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

   <div id="columna" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="background-color:yellow; height:500px;">
   <div id="elementa" style="background-color:red;">AAAA</div>
   <div id="elementb" style="background-color:blue;">BBBB</div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: `event.target.id` might get you there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: You're missing information here. I modified the drop area on the [W3 TryIt](http://www.w3schools.com/Html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop) to match your drop area and was able to drop their image onto the appropriate `div`s.

Comment: Tony: I tried it, getting the code (updated above), now with color codes. Note that I set the ondrop for the yellow div, but when dropping above the red or blue, the image will append in to the inner divs.

Comment: Make sure to use @ notation to address users so we get notified. I've posted an answer that does what you desire.

Comment: i'll rather add an answer :-)

Comment: @Tony Thx for pointing out, I'll start using @ :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to always drag to the parent of the drop element, or some known drop target, change:

```
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)); 
// to
document.getElementById('columna').appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
```

You can replace `document.getElementById('columna')` to any selector you want.

Answer (score 0):

To change the last line in the javascript to:

```
  ev.currentTarget.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
```

seems to make it.